# JSON array parsing in java

Tags: java, json, parsing, xstream

Here is my code

```
String json = "{product:{\"controls\": [[\"fire\", \"na\"], [\"jump\", \"na\"], [\"movement\", \"arrow\"]], \"languages\": [\"en\",\"br\"]}}";
XStream xstream = new XStream(new JettisonMappedXmlDriver());
xstream.alias("product", Product.class);
Product product = (Product)xstream.fromXML(json);
System.out.println(product);
```

But i am getting this error

```
Exception in thread "main" com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$DuplicateFieldException: controls
---- Debugging information ----
duplicate-field     : controls
class               : Product
required-type       : Product
path                : /product/controls[2]
line number         : -1
-------------------------------
```

The code works for non array data.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Paste your Product class.

Answer (score 0):

Use annotation for arraylists class members like:

```
@XStreamImplicit
private List<String> content;
```

Comment: I removed the xstream code and did a basic JSON parsing and it is working fine now.